# PYTHON 3 | urlextract package | urlextract.cachefile.CacheFileError: Default cache file does not exist

Tags: python, url, text, outlook, data-extraction

I have this script from a few months ago which was working fine, but right now it gives me a weird error. The script is a simple one that extract URLs from emails.
it is working correctly in my test env but when I export it as an exe file it throws this error:

```
C:\Users\tyagi\Desktop\Localization_Download.exe
Extracting download links from outlook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
File "urlextract\urlextract_core.py", line 97, in __init__
File "urlextract\cachefile.py", line 61, in __init__
File "urlextract\cachefile.py", line 88, in _get_default_cache_file_path
urlextract.cachefile.CacheFileError: Default cache file does not exist 
'C:\Users\tyagi\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI146482\urlextract\data\tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt'!
[7456] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

This is the script:

```
##############################################################
# interacting with outlook to fetch the URL & download all the files
#############################################################
print("Extracting download links from outlook")

from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(2)
inbox_folder = root_folder.Folders.Item(2)
localisation_folder = inbox_folder.Folders['localisation']

messages = localisation_folder.items

bodylist = []
for mail in messages:
    body_content = mail.body
    bodylist.append(body_content)


####### exporting all outlook emails as a text file

with open("Emailfile.txt", 'w') as output:
   for row in bodylist:
       output.write(str(row) + '\n')


####### extracting target links from that text file


 from urlextract import URLExtract

 extractor = URLExtract()
 finalUrlList = []
 with open("Emailfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       urls = extractor.find_urls(line,True)
       finalUrlList.append(urls)

 from pandas import DataFrame
 df = DataFrame(finalUrlList,columns=['download urls'])
 df = df[df['download urls'].notna()]
 df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

running it as an administrator is not an option

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In file catchefile.py line 73 change:

```
return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self._DATA_DIR)
```

to

```
return '' #os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self._DATA_DIR)
```

and insert to path of main file this downloaded filetext: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).